# http error 403 for vsphere login page

Tags: virtualization, http, vmware-vsphere

I am running a vcenter server, and created a desktop shortcut for the vsphere webclient login, it works well, but after a certain time, around 2 weeks the desktop shortcut will no longer work, and instead display a http error 403, if i mnually enter the FQDN of my vCenter Server i can connect to the vSphere webclient no problem, is there a way to fix this, so i don't have to create a new desktop shortcut every few weeks ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you shared the target of your bookmark.

Answer (score 0):

The URL of my vCenter bookmark is:

```
https://vcenter.example.com/ui/
```

I never experienced your problem.

Comment: this is very odd, my bookmark always comes out to something very long like
"https://hostname.domainname.local/websso/SAML2/SSO/vsphere.local?SAMLRequest="a sheer endless amount of random characters"

Comment: That amount of random characters is a token that expires at some point. That's the reason why you get an error some day.

Comment: is there a way to create a desktop shortcut without the token, for example one where i can manually enter the URL ? i am using chrome, but whenever i create the shortcut this token is included

Comment: So? Just edit the bookmark and remove it?

Comment: this works just fine with the bookmark in the browser, but i honestly have no idea how to edit the URL in the desktop shortcut

Comment: scratch that, i found the answer in this thread 
https://superuser.com/questions/1588128/set-custom-url-for-chrome-chromium-desktop-app